# Edit Image After Camera Captured from Android Device with Jquery mobile + PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I need to capture and Use my finger or pen mark some place on image and to save it to file;

How to do this ?

I use this function.

```
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,quality: 20, **allowEdit**: true }); 
}
```

Comment: The code! The unformated code! It burns!

Answer (score 2):

As documented in the [Android Quirks section of CameraOptions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions_android_quirks) the allowEdit parameter is not supported.

If you want to mark up a picture you'll need to load it into a canvas element and draw on it yourself.

Comment: You mean a JS canvas, right? but is possible to save that as a jpg file without uploading to a server?

Answer (score 0):

Look at my pull request [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/12)

Keep it simple :)